# Расположить выпадающий список относительно контейнера

Tags: css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, position, css-grid

Есть следующая html-разметка:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button></button>
    <menu></menu>
</div>
```

Здесь button - кнопка, по нажатию на которую выпадает список, которым является menu. Впрочем не важно, как именно это происходит, суть в том, что список имеет position: absolute. При этом вся страница условно ограничена контейнером, за пределами которого этого списка быть не должно. Также над списком есть стрелка, заданная с помощью before. Возможно ли без применения js сделать так, чтобы список был по возможности ровно по середине относительно кнопки, но при этом не выходил за контейнер, а также чтобы стрелка была в любом случае по середине?

Вот css:

```
:root {
    --size-container: 1140px; /* Может быть разный */
    --size-container-col: calc(var(--size-container) / 12);
    --size-container-padding: calc((100vw - var(--size-container)) / 2);
}

.dropdown {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.dropdown > menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: var(--size-container-padding) /* Если задаю right, не могу расположить по середине */
    margin-top: 90px;
    border: 2px solid #aaaaaa;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transform: translateY(-60px);
    transition-property: opacity, transform, box-shadow;
}
.dropdown > menu:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -17px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: solid #aaaaaa;
    border-width: 2px 0 0 2px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

С заданным right размером container-padding в любом случае будет на таком расстоянии от правого края

[image: С заданным right размером container-padding в любом случае будет на таком расстоянии от правого края]

Без right, естественно, выходит за рамки условного контейнера

[image: Без right, естественно, выходит за рамки условного контейнера]

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы элемент с `position: absolute;` был "абсолютным" относительно родителя, нужно родителю поставить `position: relative;`

```css
body {
  margin-top: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent, .child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  display: block;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
</div>

<div class="parent relative">
  <div class="child">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Так мне и не нужно делать его относительно родителя, ведь так я точно не смогу расположить его относительно контейнера.

Comment: @IkorJefocur, тогда дополните вопрос кодом и примером как должно быть.

Comment: @CblPoK2513, Я не знаю что еще сюда добавить. Вроде все описал. Если в моем коде убрать right, то будет работать все, кроме того, что элемент может вылезти за контейнер или вообще за документ. Вот и все. Нужна альтернатива, которая будет ограничивать элемент хотя бы относительно документа, но не прикреплять его к краю.